# Replace HTML element with string content using native JS

Tags: javascript, html

There is the following HTML code:

```
<body>
  <menu>
  </menu>
  ... other html
</body>
```

I need to replace `<menu>` tag with HTML content from variable. I know how I can change innerHTML using string variable with content (variable 'template');

```
menu.innerHTML = template;
```

Variable 'template' contains `'<ul class="menu"></ul>'`. As result I want to have the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
  ... other html
</body>
```

Comment: `using native JS` no jQuery?

Comment: Since you know about `innerHTML`, you may be interested to know there's a corresponding [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

Comment: @JamesThorpe That (plus a little example) should probably an answer, and not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You mention `innerHTML`; there's a corresponding [`outerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) that, when set, will replace the element and all children with your update:

```
var menu = document.getElementsByTagName('menu')[0];
menu.outerHTML = template;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/<menu>[\s\S]*?<\/menu>/, template);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = '<ul class="menu"></ul>';
var menu = document.getElementsByName('menu');
var parentMenu = menu.parentNode;
parentMenu.removeChild(menu);
parentMenu.innerHTML = str + parentMenu.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; // Select any element you want.
var target = elem.innerHTML;
elem.innerHTML = target.replace(/(<menu)/igm, '<ul class="menu"').replace(/<\/menu>/igm, '</ul>');
```